# Building CyanogenMod on Mac OS X - errors in strace

Tags: android, c, macos, macports, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to build CM9 on Mac OS X Lion, I followed all the instructions from android developers's site when set up the environment, then moved CM9 sources to my MacBook from Linux notebook via rsync, and when I rebuild it ($ brunch crespo), I'm getting this errors:

```
    In file included from external/strace/syscall.c:121:
external/strace/linux/syscallent.h:359:3: error: #error fix me
In file included from external/strace/syscall.c:121:
external/strace/linux/syscallent.h:370: error: 'SYS_sub_send' undeclared here (not in a function)
external/strace/linux/syscallent.h:371: error: 'SYS_sub_recv' undeclared here (not in a function)
external/strace/linux/syscallent.h:372: error: 'SYS_sub_sendto' undeclared here (not in a function)
external/strace/linux/syscallent.h:373: error: 'SYS_sub_recvfrom' undeclared here (not in a function)
external/strace/linux/syscallent.h:381:3: error: #error fix me
```

The following lines in syscallent.h:

```
#if SYS_socket_subcall != 300
 #error fix me
#endif
    { 8,    0,  printargs,      "socket_subcall"}, /* 300 */
    { 3,    TN, sys_socket,     "socket"    }, /* 301 */
    { 3,    TN, sys_bind,       "bind"      }, /* 302 */
    { 3,    TN, sys_connect,        "connect"   }, /* 303 */
    { 2,    TN, sys_listen,     "listen"    }, /* 304 */
    { 3,    TN, sys_accept,     "accept"    }, /* 305 */
    { 3,    TN, sys_getsockname,    "getsockname"   }, /* 306 */
    { 3,    TN, sys_getpeername,    "getpeername"   }, /* 307 */
    { 4,    TN, sys_socketpair,     "socketpair"    }, /* 308 */
    /* Line 370 */{ 4,  TN, sys_send,       "send", SYS_sub_send }, /* 309 */
```

There were no problems on Linux, why I have them on Mac OS?